# How does closure reify the data encapsulation?

Tags: javascript

In traditional OOP language, we usually use private/public to implement data encapsulation.

In Javascript, there is no private or public; someone told me, the data encapsulation can be implemented by using closure.
I am wondering how and what's the behind logic?

Comment: This is a useful reference to explain how to create private member variables in Javascript: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Comment: did you read the doc ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: JavaScript is a prototype language where  closures are based on variables / functions/ Objects scope.

Answer (score 1):

Actually isn't creating actual private members.

Check the following code:

```
function A() {
    var doStuff1 = function() { };
    this.doStuff2 = function() {
        doStuff1();
    };
};

var instance = new A();
instance.doStuff2();
```

Since `doStuff2` is declared and added to `this`, it's part of `A` instance while `doStuff1` is declared as a local variable within the constructor function, and thus, it's only accessible using closures within the same constructor.

BTW I don't like this pattern since it works great when you don't use prototypal inheritance.

Let's say I want to use prototypes:

```
function A() {
     var doStuff1 = function() {}; // ??????
};

A.prototype = {
     doStuff2: function() {
        // How do I access a local variable defined 
        // in the constructor function local scope?
     }
};
```

So, the whole pattern works in simple scenarios where you don't want to use prototypal inheritance.

Also, this pattern won't work in scenarios where you want to use `Object.create(...)`, since there's no constructor function at all...

```
// Constructor isn't ever called...
var instance = Object.create(A.prototype);
```

So, how you would implement this kind of encapsulation in JavaScript? For now isn't possible, but many libraries and frameworks have opted-in to use naming conventions to let developers know what's consumed by the library/framework code and what's intended for use in actual third-party developments.

For example:

```
function A() {

};

A.prototype = {
    ___doStuff1___: function() {},
    doStuff2: function() {
         this.___doStuff1___();
    }
};
```

After all, this is a naming convention, where members which are sorrounded by `___` are considered private or not intended for third-party developers.

Other libraries/framework use `$$` (f.e. *Angular*, `$$privateMember`).

Answer (score 1):

You can encapsulate data in a 'Class' (no real class before JavaScript 6) this way

```
var yourClass = function() {
   var privateProp = 'sometext'; //private prop
   this.prop = 1; //public


   this.getPrivateProp = function() {
       return privateProp; //access to your private prop with a closure
   }
}

var test = new yourClass();
//when you use 'new', everything in 'this' is returned in your object. 
//'privateProp' is not in 'this' but 'getPrivateProp' is. 
//You got your private data not directly accessible from outside.

test.prop; // 1
test.privateProp;//undefined
test.getPrivateProp();// 'sometext'
```

Comment: BTW you could do using Object.defineProperty and defining a getter instead of an accessor function :D

Comment: I mean `Object.defineProperty(this, "prop", { get: function() { return privateProp; } });` and then you access the value as a regular variable/property `test.pop`.

Comment: Yeah, cause my example is a getter you are right, but it was more for the sake of the example, so you could do the function you want.

Comment: I gave you this suggestion so you can teach ES5.x instead of ES4 for future visitors, but you're right, your example works to show what you wanted to explain to the OP